# Can you read a scroll with extra standard action from Haste?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, mythic-adventures

I just read a [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/2zmhja/best_mythic_spells_for_a_wizard/) on Mythic Haste. The guy says:

> As far as buffing goes, Mythic Haste is, like haste, probably the best
>   bang for you buck spell in existence. Giving your entire team +50
>   speed and an extra move action is INSANE. **It's also amazing for
>   yourself if you have a haversack full of scrolls**, like any good Wizard
>   should.

I am a bit irritated about the bold part. Does that mean that you can read a scroll with your additional standard action and get the scroll out of your backsack with the additional move action?

Just for more source:

The rules for [Haste](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste) say that you cannot use the standard action for **casting** a spell.

The scroll rules say: Activating a scroll is a standard action. I am not sure if using a scroll is casting at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No one gets an additional standard action. "Affected creatures gain an additional move action each round." -Mythic Haste
2. You can get free standard actions in a bunch of ways in Mythic, like from Amazing Initiative, and they all have the same kinds of disclaimer: "In addition, as a free action on your turn, you can expend one use
   of mythic power to take an additional standard action
   during that turn. This additional standard action can’t
   be used to cast a spell. You can’t gain an extra action in
   this way more than once per round." -Amazing Initative

But none of these are germane to your question really, which is "is activating a scroll the same as casting a spell for purposes of the "one per round" restriction?

Yes, it is.  Scrolls are a "spell completion" item, which involve you casting the spell, and taking the same (or more - a standard action or longer if the casting time is longer) to cast them. So that counts as casting a spell for all intents and purposes.

I would think spell trigger items (wands) might not be subject to this restriction, but that I'm unclear on.

Answer (score 3):

I can't read the guy's mind (you'll have to ask him), but using a scroll is "basically like casting a spell" so using it with Mythic Haste won't work.

[Quoting the SRD:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls) (emphasis mine)

> A scroll is a spell (or collection of spells) that has been stored in written form. A spell on a scroll can be used only once. The writing vanishes from the scroll when the spell is activated. **Using a scroll is basically like casting a spell.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your additional move action to **read** a scroll (because it takes a standard action). Even mythic Haste don't give you any additional standard action.

However it still takes a move action to **retrieve** a scroll from your haversack, so this additional action is welcome for that. You can, for example, at the same turn retrieve a healing scroll, go to your dying friend and cast it on him.